# What is the meaning of Detective Tom words: “you want my scalp nailed to your wall”?

Tags: meaning

In ***Street Kings***, Detective Tom & Captain James Biggs have some conversation:

> Captain James Biggs: Did you really think I was gonna do nothing
>   about you?
>
> Detective Tom: If you are gonna do something, do it now. **I know you
>   want my scalp nailed to your wall.**

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: You should [wait longer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer. Also, I'm willing to give users the benefit of the doubt here, but you should generally include [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like what you think and any research you have done to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reference to *scalping*. From Wikipia

> [Scalping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalping) is the act of cutting or tearing a part of the human scalp, with hair attached, from the head of an enemy as a trophy. Scalp-taking is considered part of the broader cultural practice of the taking and display of human body parts as trophies, and may have developed as an alternative to the taking of human heads, for scalps were easier to take, transport, and preserve for subsequent display. Scalping independently developed in various cultures in both the Old and New Worlds.

I assume it's figurative. Biggs doesn't really want Tom's scalp (and Tom knows that). It's a creative way of saying "I know you want to defeat/kill me/take revenge" (whatever the situation might be).